# Login denied with correct Password after grub-rescue

Tags: login, fstab, grubrescue, ecryptfs, passwd

On thursday last week i made a mistake when trying to enlarge my Win7 partition with the Windows tool. 
As a result i had my bootpartition deleted from the partition table an could not boot, neither Kubuntu 14.04 nor the Win7. With the Gparted Live Disk and the indluded testdisk-tool i managed to salvage my Partitiontable, but had some changes made in the numeration of the partitions: /boot & /root were now on sda3 instead of sda7 and i originally had my /home transferred to sda6 which now became sda5.

I then configured grub via the rescue shell to use the new partitions for boot and root.
After that i was able to enter Win7 as usual and had every option available i had before, including my individuallized grub wallpaper.

I made my changes persistent via the recovery mode rootshell:

```
root@mymachine:~# mount -o remount,rw /
root@mymachine:~# update-grub
```

So my boot procedure seemed to be the sameas before again.

Unfortunately i was wrong and i have now trouble logging into my Kubuntu account. I have no doubt that i enter my password correctly, but it is rejected. Same error occurs when i change to the shell by Alt+Shift+F2.

So here is what i already checked:

I tried setting a new password as root:

```
root@maymachine:~# passwd myuser
passwd: Access denied
passwd: Password not changed
```

I checked my  root permissions for the folder /etc/passwd

```
root@meinPC:~# ls -l /etc/passwd
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2476 Jun 22 13:25 /etc/passwd
root@meinPC:~# ls -l /etc/shadow 
root@meinPC:~# cat /etc/group | grep root
root:x:0:
root@meinPC:~# pwck
User >>myuser<<: Directory >>/home/myuser<< does not exist.
User >>guestuser<<: Directory >>/home/guestuser<< does not exist.
#same for all systemusers
pwck: no changes
root@mymachine:~# faillog -u myuser
Login       Fehlvers.   Maximum    Letzter                  Auf

myuser        0           0      01/01/70 01:00:00 +0100
```

So i concluded that my homedirectory might not be where it should be and checked:

```
root@mymachine:~# su - myuser
No directory, logging in with HOME=/
myuser@mymachine:~$ du -sh /home
4,0K     /home
myuser@mymachine:~$ ls -arH /home
. :
. ..
```

My /home is obvyously empty. Because i had my homedir transferred to a separate partition i checked whether fstab was ok:

```
root@mymachine:~# blkid
[...]
/dev/sda3: UUID="1834fa5f-a225-49e3-a034-6ea07c4c5199" TYPE="ext4"
/dev/sda5: UUID="f46496ef-9e33-4a23-9255-2a32ad447409" TYPE="ext4"
root@mymachine:~# less /etc/fstab
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blrkid' to point the universally unique identifier for a device ....
#
# /was on /dev/sda8 during the installation
UUDI=1834fa54-a225-49e3-a034-6ea07c4c5199 /       ext4     errors=remount-ro   0    1
# /home was on /dev/sda6 during installation
UUID=f46496ef-9e33-4a23-9255-2a32ad447409  /home   ext4     defaults            0    2
~
~
~
(END)
```

It seems nothing is wrong with fstab, so i repeated the installation of the dynamic links for the encryption of my user's directory.

```
root@mymachine:~# ln -s /home/.ecryptfs/$USER/.Private ~/.Private
root@mymachine:~# ln -s /home/.ecryptfs/$USER/.ecryptfs ~/.ecryptfs
root@mymachine:~# chown $USER:$USER ~
```

After that i rebooted but had no positive result, so i checked whether my bootroutine was missing

```
mount -a
```

I booted into recovery mode and enteredthe rootshell:

```
root@mymachine:~# ls -a home
. ..
root@mymachine:~# mount -a
root@mymachine:~# ls -a home
. ..
```

So the fstab seems not to be the problem.

```
root@mymachine:~# mount /dev/sda5 /home
root@mymachine:~# ls -a /home
. .. .directory .ecryptfs guestaccount lost+found myuser .Trash-0
root@mymachine:~# ls -a /home/myuser
. .. Access-Your-Private-Data.desktop .ecryptfs -kde .Private README.txt
```

so the decryption of my homedirectory seems to be the Problem. I really need help from here because I'm running out of ideas.
Most steps summarized above were used in the recovery shells and via chrooting from a livesystem into my system.

My password is still denied, i also cannot login to my geustaccaount. Because there is no password needed for this account, no errormesssage is prompted, but nothing happens.

Comment: Tried to at least salvage my private data 'ecrypt-mount-private' but recieved 'ERROR: Encrypted private directory is not set up properly'